# fs.js binding.lstat(baseLong) in Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have updated my angular CLI project and also today had windows updates and now I am getting the follow when I do any ng command.

```
C:\Dat\L\Web\Ng\net-incident>ng serve
fs.js:1649
      binding.lstat(baseLong);
              ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Phillip'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1649:15)
    at toRealPath (module.js:156:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:205:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:534:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Additionally **C:\Users\Phillip** is not the account I am running as and if I  login as that user it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your directory permissions which you specified. Better move the folder from c drive to another unrestricted drive.

Comment: The %PATH% variable had a hard coded appdata\roaming\npm path. I changed it to %USERPROFILE%, and reopened the command prompt and it was fine.